# Why \renewcommand with optional arguments doesn't compile?

Tags: renewcommand

What's wrong with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\let\first\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{\first{#1}}
\let\second\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{\second{#1}} % works till this line
\let\third\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{\third[#1]{#2}}
\section[foo]{Hello}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile.

Comment: `\section` is just parsing for `[` then using (the same) internal command at each stage which you are over-writitng.

Comment: Instead of `\let` use `\NewCommandCopy`, reason: see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ***never*** use `\let` for commands with optional arguments.

Let's see what happens in this case, taking into account that

```
\renewcommand\section[2][]{\second{#1}}
```

actually defines *two* commands: one is `\section` which takes no argument and the other one is `\\section` (with a backslash in its name).

The job of (the redefined) `\section` is to check for a following `[` and to call `\\section` with the appropriate two arguments, the first being the default if no `[` followed `\section`.

Now you do `\let\third\second` and `\renewcommand\section[2][]{\third[#1]{#2}` will basically redefine `\\section` in terms of itself, causing an infinite loop.

If you use `\NewCommandCopy` instead of `\let` (or `\LetLtxMacro` with the `letltxmacro` if you have an older LaTeX), there will be no infinite loop.

Comment: How do you even define a command with a name such as `\\section`? Something like `\expandafter\def\csname\\section\endcsname{<something>}`? Or must I escape the backslash some other way? (I assume yes, since `\\ ` is a completely different macro.)

Comment: `\expandafter\def\csname \string\section \endcsname ...` assuming normal `\escapechar`

Comment: @plante Makes sense. So a command name can contain a backslash. I wonder: Is it possible to have a command name *ending* in a backslash? Obviously, `\\ ` is one such, but can it be done with command names having more than one character?

Comment: @Gaussler You can certainly have a command name ending in a backslash: assuming a standard value for `\escapechar`, `\expandafter\def\csname test\expandafter\gobble\string\\\endcsname{test}` will do, with `\def\gobble#1{}` (in LaTeX there is `\@gobble`). If you activate `\tracingassigns=1`, you get `{changing \test\=\relax}` `{into \test\=macro:->test}`

Comment: Why is this `\gobble` necessary? I don’t understand the logic of this this definition of `\test\ `.

Comment: @Gaussler ``\string\\`` will produce ``\\`` and we want to remove one backslash.

Comment: Makes sense. A related question: It seems that `\csname\endcsname` (the empty command name) is defined and equal to `\relax`. Why in the world is that the case?

Comment: @Gaussler Anytime you do `\csname...\endcsname` the sequence is defined as equivalent to `\relax` unless it already has a definiition.